# AppState and redux toolkit on android

Tags: react-native, react-redux, rect

current I'm using AppState to know when the app is coming back to the active state and inside there I'm making an API call with redux see cold below.

```
useEffect(() => {
 const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", (nextAppState) => {
 if (
 appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
 nextAppState === "active"
      ) {
 getTimes();
 dispatch(getLocation());
 dispatch(getCity());
      }

 appState.current = nextAppState;
 setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
    });

 return () => {
 subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

It works fine on an iPhone but when I deploy it to an android the API calls keep getting called and never stop if I comment out the redux call and redeploy it to an android phone everything works fine and it doesn't keep refreshing.